# unique values in function of another variable in R

Tags: r, unique

After some search I did not find any way to select unique values in function of another variable.

I have a dataframe of two variables (ID, score). In this df, some ID are duplicates, and some scores are unknown (na). I would like to have unique values of ID and keep the one with the score if two IDs have both a "na" or a known value. exemple:

```
df  = data.frame(id = c("1","2","3","4","5","3","5","6","7","7"),
                 score = c("4","2","na","6","7","8","na","10","na","9"))
```

I would like to keep:

```
id score
1     4
2     2
3     8
4     6
5     7
6    10
7     9
```

I tried the `unique()` function or `distinct()` but neither could select in each case the right id to keep (the one without "na").

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your wish is just remove rows with `score == "na"` you can just filter the data like this. Note that in your example data "na" doenst mean NA. So if you want to filter values really identiyed by NA your need to create a !is.na() statment. Try this:

```
    df %>%
     filter(score != "na" | !is.na(score) == T)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.
I forgot to precise that some IDs did't have a score at all (NA) and I have to keep them as well. Thus !is.na would discard them. Thank you for the precision of "na" --> NA. 

However, I think I did find the solution:


`df  = data.frame(id = c("1","2","3","4","5","3","5","6","7","7","8"),
                 score = c("4","2",NA,"6","7","8",NA,"10",NA,"9",NA))

df %>%
  arrange(id, score)%>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = T)`